# PHP Script Socket Stay Connected

Tags: php, sockets, connection, socks

How can I connect to a socket in PHP without getting disconnected on the next page load? pfsockopen does not work.

I wrote a php cli script that waits for a user input its in a while loop and the socket connection stays alive. Do you know a solution how to pass a command to a running php script and return the content?

Answer (score 0):

look at php.net socket **keep alive**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

[PHP: Connection: keep-alive problem reading socket data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384741/php-connection-keep-alive-problem-reading-socket-data)